# What is the difference build types: nightly,release,debug,dev

Tags: android, android-build-type

I wonder what is the difference between these build types and what its effects on code

in Android Studio - gradle

- nightly
- release
- debug
- dev

it is already there and question has already been answered, please direct me to the link

Comment: With? Android Studio? Godzilla? The Moon? Please, make a full question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You would have to ask whoever defined those build types. `nightly` and `dev` are not part of any standard Android environment that I know of.

Comment: sorry, in Android studio - Gradle

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a specific programming issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally those will have different amounts of debugging/optimizations/obfuscations in them...

- debug   - signed with the debug key, debuggable, not proguarded
- release - signed with the release key, not debuggable, proguarded

The terms nightly & dev don't have standard definitions, but probably something like:

- dev     - maybe configured to point to an internal server for testing, debuggable
- nightly - perhaps done as a clean build, similar to release